# Flask IE11 Timeout Issue

Tags: python, google-chrome, flask, internet-explorer-11

For the Flask gurus:

I'm running Flask v12 listening on localhost.

Navigating the define route works fine in Chrome.

IE11 also works, but commonly times out. When debugging in Flask, it appears that Flask isn't even receiving the request (the route's method is not called). The network monitor in IE's developer console just says the request is pending.

If I access the page via Chrome while IE11 appears to be in the middle of timing out, the IE page will load after Chrome finishes loading.

I do not have the ability to manipulate the settings on the client, so the fix would have to be server side, if there is one.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

**Example:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/dashboard/<string:report>/<string:region>/<string:lob>/', defaults={'branch': None, 'team': None})
@app.route('/dashboard/<string:report>/<string:region>/<string:lob>/<string:branch>', defaults={'team': None})
@app.route('/dashboard/<string:report>/<string:region>/<string:lob>/<string:branch>/<string:team>')
def dashboard(report, region, lob, branch, team):
    return "TEST", 200, {'ContentType': 'text/plain'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Edit 1**: Updated Werkzeug to 12.1 as per another thread. Still the same problem.

**Edit 2**: It appears Chrome also starts exhibiting the same behavior if IE starts acting up. Chrome fails to respond unless IE refreshes. Server needs to be restarted. Also, IE consistently freezes if you open a fresh browser and paste the URL in relatively quickly.

**Edit 3**:

[image: IE Network Monitor]

[image: Console Output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @davidism setting the Flask server to `threaded=True` resolves the IE11 issue.

IE was acting this way occasionally after first page, and after relaunch of the entire server... so there couldn't have been a pending request.